# Check if app is reinstalled without storing unique id

Tags: flutter, in-app-purchase

When my app is first installed, the user gets 5 free consumables. After the consumables are finished, the user then has the option to get purchase 5 additional consumables. Is there a way to check if the app was previously installed. I don't want the user to uninstall and reinstall to get 5 free consumables again.

The plugin I'm using, [in_app_purchase](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/main/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase), allows [retrieval of past consumables](https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/main/packages/in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase#restoring-previous-purchases), so I thought I could have the user purchase a free consumable on startup, which I could later retrieve if the app is installed, but I don't want the user to go through any extra steps to use the app for the first time.

I would prefer a solution that doesn't require storing a unique id because that would require backend code and getting a unique id isn't possible on iOS.

Comment: did you find the answer for this ? I'm also trying implement similar use case to monitor first time free credits and prevent user from app deletion and re-install to get the free credits.

Comment: I think it is impossible. Only way around this is to have the user sign in.